# Inserting a unicode API response containing emojis into Mysql using Python mysql.connector

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I'm connecting to the Facebook Graph API using Python and the curl response delivers a bunch of data in Unicode format. I am trying to insert this data into a mysql database using the python mysql.connector driver but I keep running into encoding errors.

Specifically, I get this type of error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)`
or
`File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 243, in execute raise errors.ProgrammingError(str(err)) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 519: ordinal not in range(128)`

My database fields are all utf8mb4 and I *believe* my encoding is all UTF8 as well. So I can't figure out why I'm getting ASCII errors.

The error is happening on the 'caption' field of Instagram posts being returned which includes emojis so I'm 99% sure this is the problem, when commenting out this line everything else works as expected.

So far I have tried:

Adding `use_unicode=True, charset='utf8'` to the mysql.connector.connect command (according to the docs this is the default anyway)

Adding `#!/usr/bin/python # encoding=utf8` to the top of the script

Adding `use_unicode=True, charset='ascii'` to the mysql.connector.connect command because why not try it

Tried combinations of `caption.decode('utf')` `caption.encode('utf8')` on the variable before the mysql insert directive.

I can't find any reference to ASCII in the mysql.connector documentation, so I'm not sure why it's trying to do the conversion.

In reference to the second error above, when going to that line of cursor_cext.py in the mysql.connector package the lines look like this:

```
try:
    if isunicode(operation):
        stmt = operation.encode(self._cnx.python_charset)
    else:
        stmt = operation
except (UnicodeDecodeError, UnicodeEncodeError) as err:
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(str(err))
```

I have previously done something similar with PHP successfully using the old Instagram API but now that they have changed to the Facebook Graph API for Instagram I decided to use Python as it appeared easier but now I don't know where to go with these errors.

Answer (score 1):

When you combine Unicode and byte strings in Python 2 (eg. `"a" + u"a"`), there's an implicit coercion calling `.decode()` on the byte string (`"a"`). The default codec for this method is ASCII in Python 2.

Encoding errors that happen during implicit coercion can be pretty tricky to track down.
Implicit coercion is gone in Python 3, so both user code and library code are forced to keep `str` and `bytes` separate.

I suggest you upgrade to Python 3 if you can.
It might not immediately make your code work, but it's more likely that you will find out where to explicitly set the encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and suggestion. I have 3 installed but have been procrastinating switching. If I can't find a suitable answer I'll refactor and change the interpreter to 3.

Comment: If you consequently use `unicode` for text and `str` for (binary) data, you should be fine. The problem is occasionally that some Python 2 libraries don't stick to this principle.